# Two or more tables that are mostly synchronized in database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-replication

I'm using PostgreSQL and I need to have two or more tables that are mostly synchronized in my database, such that an `Add/Delete/Update` to a row in sub table is made to the master table.

I'm not sure if trigger can be used in this situation because in my situation the sub table may be truncated and load in with new set of data

Any idea how to implement that ?

Example:

```
Employee_Sub1:
 id    name    version
+------+-------+--------+
 101    John     1
 102    David    1
 105    Azi      1

Employee_Sub2:
 id    name    version
+------+-------+--------+
 101    John     1
 102    DavidX   2       <- Sub2 having updated value for id 102
 105    Azi      1
 107    Marry    1

Employee_Sub3:
 id    name    version
+------+-------+--------+
 101    John    1
 105    Azi     1
 110    devil   1       <- Sub3 having new row of data
```

The Employee_Final table shall look like this :

```
Employee_Final:
 id    name    version
+------+-------+--------+
 101    John    1
 102    DavidX  2
 105    Azi     1
 107    Marry   1
 110    devil   1
```

Comment: One possibility might be creating the master table as a view and having the actual data only in the subtables. However, this means that the query for creating the view is run each time the data is accessed, so if the query if a heavy join and it is run constantly, this might not be scalable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html); see [PL/PgSQL trigger procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) for how to implement them in PL/PgSQL. Use `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` triggers on each of `Employee_Sub1`, `Employee_Sub2`, and `Employee_Sub3` to propagate their changes to `Employee_Final`.

There's also a bit of a [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) feel about this question, but I'm not sure inheritance is a good fit.

Usually when you're changing IDs you use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` foreign key references, but that won't work here because you need it reversed, where the PK gets updated when you change the FK. That's another job for a trigger; you have to compare the `NEW` and `OLD` record IDs and update the master table if the ID has changed.

Comment: I'm not sure if trigger can be used in this situation because in my situation the sub table may be truncated and load in with new set of data. Sorry for not highlight earlier in the question.  any possibility without trigger ?

Comment: @Azi You can use `ON TRUCATE` triggers to cope with that. Otherwise do as @Edu suggests and make the master table a view.

Answer (score 1):

You might use table inheritance. At first, you create master table with no data and create child table from master table with inheritance option. When you select from master table, resultset includes dataset of child table. Visit http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-inherit.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. By the way table inheritance seems like UNION and the id field keep repeated even set as a primary key. Also how the delete row been handled in the table inheritance?

Comment: There is no inheritance PK. data modification happens with in child table so when you select from master table, it just select data from all of the child table.

Comment: If you want to handle ID throughout all over the child tables, you can use single sequence so that each of child table share the sequence for the ID columns. it's like.... create table tab_name (column_name varchar(1) default nextval('sequence_name'))

Answer (score 0):

Normally you create a trigger on the source table and it works out whether to update or insert into the target table.